# Animating plotly.express.area

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to understand how I can animate an area plot using plotly. However, I am just not getting it. I tried to create a very simple example that in my opinion should work, but it doesn't:

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas

dfa = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Decile': ['0.2', '0.1', '0.8', '0.1', '0.4', '0.9'],
    'Year': [1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981]
})
px.area(dfa, title='Test', animation_frame='Year')
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

[image: Test Output]

And when I move the slider to 1981 the plot gets empty:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I want the area to plot [0.2, 0.1, 0.8] for 1980 and [0.1, 0.4, 0.9] for 1981.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues

1. *Decile* is it really a string and should be treated as a categorical?  Have converted to number
2. given the ranges of values between animation frames are not consistent, these need to be explicitly set

#### full code

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas

dfa = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "Decile": ["0.2", "0.1", "0.8", "0.1", "0.4", "0.9"],
        "Year": [1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981],
    }
)
dfa["Decile"] = pd.to_numeric(dfa["Decile"])
fig = px.area(dfa, title="Test", animation_frame="Year")

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_range=dfa.index.values[[0, -1]],
    yaxis_range=[dfa["Decile"].min(), dfa["Decile"].max()],
)
fig
```